# heatmap.js getting jumpy after pan

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap

I'm using heatmap.js + googlemap.

Heatmap displays perfectly and I can zoom in and out without problems.
but once I have dragged the map, the rendering gets jumpy. 
That is, on refresh, it displays well (in sync with the drag), but immediatly translates the heatmap to the place it was before I dragged. It remains jumpy like this at every refresh.

code is as follow :

```
this.options = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: false,
          scrollwheel: true,
          draggable: true,
          navigationControl: true,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          scaleControl: true,
          disableDoubleClickZoom: false
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$el, this.options);

        this.heatmap = new HeatmapOverlay(this.map, {
            "radius":20,
            "visible":true, 
            "opacity":60
        });


        // this is important, because if you set the data set too early, the latlng/pixel projection doesn't work
        var that = this;
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, "idle", function(){
            that.updateMap(that.map);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'bounds_changed', function(e) {
            that.updateMap(that.map);
    });
```

...

```
updateMap: function (map, callback){
        var bound = map.getBounds();
        var queryObject = {
                north: bound.getNorthEast().lat(),
                south: bound.getSouthWest().lat(),
                east : bound.getNorthEast().lng(),
                west : bound.getSouthWest().lng(),
        };
        $.getJSON('areaGeolocations', queryObject, function(data) {
            var geoData = new Array();

            $.each(data.geolocationLogs, function(key, val) {
                geoData.push({lng:val.longitude, lat:val.latitude, count:1});
            });

            that.heatmap.setDataSet({max: 5, data: geoData});
            if(callback)
                callback();
        });
    },
```

any idea ?

cheers!